# Create Web Enabled Image workflow step. Is it possible to add multiple rendition sizes?

Tags: java, workflow, customization, aem

I want that `Create web enabled Image` workflow step generate 3 different sizes.

I cannot understand how to set it I am tryed like in my picture but after this adding I see NumberFormatException in logs.

[image]

I f I write width: 50 height: 50 I see following in my crx:

[image]

Thus cq adds my  50x50 rendition + 1280x1280 by default. I want to add some my renditions(30x30 and 40x40) and I don't want to see 1280x1280 by default.

Is it possible to configure?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to add more than one rendition for that process. May be you can consider extending it and creating your own workflow process.

Comment: Can you provide example how to extends step?